# PHP Average values in column based on year date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im working on webpage that should average values in a given column based on the current year. 
Ive got the following code:

```
public function getElecReadings(){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT AVG(ElecUsage), DateAdded FROM elec_readings  WHERE AccountNumber = '" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "'");
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
```

As i understand that should select the average from all the values within the `ElecUsage` column. However i was wondering how i can select all the average values from the column based on the current year that were in. I know to get the current year i can do something along the lines of : `<?php echo date("Y"); ?>` which will echo out 2016.

My DateAdded column is stored as a date type. So today would be 2016-04-19. Is there any way to extract the 2016 from the column and apply it to the select statement and then display the averaged value in a textbox on my HTML page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered the question yourself:

```
$year = date("Y");
$year = "$year%";
$stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT AVG(ElecUsage), DateAdded FROM 
elec_readings  WHERE AccountNumber = '" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "' 
AND DateAdded LIKE '$year'");
```

That will extract all the account numbers where the year is 2016-andsomething, which I think is what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no errors so far, i was just wondering if theres a way to store the averaged value in a variable and then call that?

Answer (score 1):

**its about your query. You have to select avg from the table where year(date) = 'current_year'**

so your code could be like this :

```
public function getElecReadings(){
        try {
            $current_year = date('Y');
            $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT AVG(ElecUsage), 
            DateAdded FROM elec_readings  WHERE year(DateAdded) = '$current_year' and AccountNumber = '" .$_SESSION['user_session'] . "'");
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
```

**also you can use another query to extract every average for every year:**

```
SELECT AVG(ElecUsage), year(DateAdded) FROM elec_readings GROUP BY YEAR(DateAdded)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to put year(DateAdded) = '$current_year'

Comment: Is there a way to store the average value in a variable and then call it?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meen by store it in a variable.
but you can assign it an alias within the query itself
as select AVG(ElecUsage) as average ...
then when you fetch the $stmt rows you can call it by that name
as 
    echo $row['average'] ;

Comment: try to edit your query as the above comment. so add as average. ok then 

    $result = getElecReadings();
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['average'];

Comment: or you can use : 
$result = getElecReadings();
$row =$result->fetchObject();
echo $row->average;

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this :

```
public function getElecReadings(){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT AVG(ElecUsage), DateAdded FROM elec_readings  WHERE AccountNumber = '" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "' AND CurrentYear LIKE '%2016'");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

It worked for me. Just grab the year with PHP as you said before and then ouput that variable instead.

Comment: That would work too just a little unsure as to how i would store the averages value and call it in my HTML page

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the question was about filtering the results by the year only. If you want to display the results in a HTML template, just call that function  and store the result in a PHP variable. Then you have to loop through the results and echoed them. Let me know if you need me to update my answer if you need more help

Comment: no youre right. I do just want to filter the result by the year and then average the usage column but i need to display the average in a textbox and im a little unsure how to do that. If you could update your answer id appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get current year with mysql using `CURDATE()`.
Just add this condition to your select statement

```
AND YEAR(DateAdded) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```